# Changing Figure A to Figure B

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have tried to make my small cube change to a high cube when I press the upper arrow, but I can't figure it out:(

Please help me, if you can.

In my game it's important to do so, or my idea won't work.

I have tried:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FormShifting : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject myObject1;
    public GameObject myObject2;
    int high;

    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetKey("up") && high == 0)
        {
            myObject1.SetActive(false);
            myObject2.SetActive(true);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("down") && high == 1)
        {
            myObject2.SetActive(false);
            myObject1.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include what the problem that you are experiencing is. Off the bat I see that you never set the value of `high` and therefore it could never enter your second if-statement.

Comment: I have decidet to take away the high statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Input.GetKeyDown` to know when a key is just pressed, `Input.GetKey` is `true` only when a button is kept pressed.
Moreover, if possible, don't use the string argument, but use the `KeyCode` enum.
Finally, you need to change the value of `high` or the second if will never be `true`.

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class FormShifting : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject myObject1;
    public GameObject myObject2;
    int high;

    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && high == 0)
        {
            myObject1.SetActive(false);
            myObject2.SetActive(true);
            high = 1;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow) && high == 1)
        {
            myObject2.SetActive(false);
            myObject1.SetActive(true);
            high = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: On the left of my answer, under the downvote arrow, you should see a gray checkmark, click on it to accept the answer.